# Duplicate handling using case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a table tab1. Case 1:if no dups then display col1 data. Case 2: If I find duplicate in col1,then max of sr_no should be considered. While considering this, I need to consider only data='xyz' others should be ignored.

Tab1 structure(not exactly) Col1 Sr Data

Could you please help me with the query. Tried with case condition but not getting desired output.

For example

```
Col1. Sr. Data.
1234. 1. ABC
1234. 2. MNO
1234. 3. XYZ
1234. 4. ABC
2345. 1. ABC
```

OUTPUT

```
Col1. Sr. Data
1234. 3. XYZ (as it is duplicated, select max of sr and data=XYZ)
2345. 1. ABC (As it is unique no checks for max and data=XYZ)
```

Comment: Please post your table structure with data examples, what you have tried, and repeatable code.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify your logic. Is considering `XYZ` rows only applicable in Case 2 or is it applicable to both cases? What is a duplicate? Is it two rows with the same `Col1` or is it two rows with the same `Col1` and the same `Data`? I.e does `1234` have a duplicate because there is more than 1 row or because there are duplicate `data` values? How many rows would you expect to be returned if the 4th row was not present and there were no duplicate data values for `Col1`? Would it be all the rows or just 1 row for `Col1 = 1234`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `row_number()` with a priority for `XYZ`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by (case when data = 'XYZ' then 1 else 2 end), sr desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic appears to be:

```sql
SELECT Col1, Sr, Data
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         CASE max_cnt
         WHEN 1
         THEN 1
         ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Sr DESC )
         END AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           MAX( cnt ) OVER ( PARTITION BY Col1 ) AS max_cnt
    FROM   (
      SELECT t.*,
             COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY Col1, Data ) AS cnt
      FROM   table_name t
    ) t
  ) t
  WHERE max_cnt = 1
  OR    data = 'XYZ'
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Col1, Sr, Data ) AS
SELECT 1234, 1, 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 2, 'MNO' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 3, 'XYZ' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1234, 4, 'ABC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2345, 1, 'ABC' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | COL1 | SR | DATA |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1234 | 3 | XYZ |
> | 2345 | 1 | ABC |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c9cfd1b605213bbd8734c0ff9efb31f7)*